# Components do not change when a hooked element is Changed

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Currently, the details of the elements which I want to display are saved at `Info.js`.
`Parent.js` is responsible for importing the details needed and then injecting them respectively into each `Child.js`  by .map function as the info stored at `Info.js` is an array.

I want to dynamically display the relative Child component by the button pressed by users. For example, when the user clicked "First-Tier" button at `Parent.js`, only the `Child.js` component with the category of "First-Tier" will be shown. At this moment, my code is not working. I believe the problem is at useEffect but I cannot figure out how to fix this.

I am looking forward to receiving your inspirations. Thanks and please stay safe.

--->  Parent.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Info from "./Info";
import Child from "./Child";

let Category = ["All", "First-Tier", "Second-Tier"];

const Parent = () => {
  const [categoryChosen, setCategoryChosen] = useState("All");
  let PartsShown = [...Info];
  useEffect(() => {
    PartsShown = [
      ...PartsShown.filter((e) => e.category[1] === categoryChosen),
    ];
  }, [categoryChosen, PartsShown]);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {Category.map((element) => (
          <button
            style={{ margin: 10 }}
            key={element}
            onClick={() => setCategoryChosen(element)}
          >
            {element}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div>{categoryChosen}</div>
      <div>
        {PartsShown.map((e) => (
          <Child
            key={e.name}
            name={e.name}
            category={e.category[1]}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Parent;
```

---> Child.js

```
import React from "react";

const Child = ({ name, category }) => (
  <div style={{ margin: 10 }}>
    <h1>{name}</h1>
    <p>{category}</p>
    <hr />
  </div>
);

export default Child;
```

--> Info.js

```
const Info = [
  {
    name: "A",
    description: "Description of A ",
    category: ["All", "First-Tier"],
  },
  {
    name: "B",
    description: "Description of B",
    category: ["All", "Second-Tier"],
  }
];
export default Info;
```

Comment: I think there is no problem with the useState part, but the problem occurs at useEffect part. Still attempting to understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Info from "./Info";
import Child from "./Child";

const Category = ["All", "First-Tier", "Second-Tier"];

const Parent = () => {
  const [partsShown, setPartsShownAndCategory] = useState({
    partsArray: [...Info],
    category: "All"
  });
  const changeCategory = category => {
    const PartsShown = Info.filter(
      element =>
        element.category[1] === category || element.category[0] === category
    );
    setPartsShownAndCategory({
      ...partsShown,
      category: category,
      partsArray: PartsShown
    });
  };
  console.log(partsShown);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {Category.map(element => (
          <button
            style={{ margin: 10 }}
            key={element}
            onClick={() => changeCategory(element)}
          >
            {element}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div>{partsShown.category}</div>
      <div>
        {partsShown.partsArray.map(e => (
          <Child key={e.name} name={e.name} category={partsShown.category} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Parent;
```

Comment: You don't need to use useEffect at all. I have done the changes you require and tested it on sandbox too. Hope it helps. Please do upvote both the answer and this comment. And if you need any further explanantion, I am happy to help

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/stoic-feistel-ueh2b?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: It works. Thanks. I forgot useState can wrap an object. It is mind-blowing. Please stay safe .